# Read a image from a longblob MySQL very fast

Tags: java, mysql, blob, jslider

As the title says, I wanna retrive images (stored in longblob) very fast when the jslider is moved. I have 360 cases, and it is work with no error, but the problem consist in the lag/delay of each case/image when the jslider is moved. I tested this idea with images retrived from local machine and it works very fast/clean. I know that the problem can be from the internet connection, but trust me I have at least 3-4 MB/s download/upload.

Few extra notes:
table engine: MyISAM
column: longblob with every image ~170-200 kb - .png

```
//calling jslider and setup

jslider1 = new javax.swing.JSlider();  //my jslider
jslider1.setMajorTickSpacing(10);
jslider1.setMaximum(360);
jslider1.setMinorTickSpacing(5);
jslider1.setOrientation(javax.swing.JSlider.VERTICAL);

//and my change event

private void jslider1StateChanged(javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent evt) {   
    int x = jslider1.getValue();
    switch (x) {
           case 1:

                try {
                    String sql = "select imga from test where deg ='" + x + "'";
                    pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                    rs = pst.executeQuery();

                    if (rs.next()) {
                        byte[] imagedata = rs.getBytes("imga");
                        format = new ImageIcon(imagedata);
                        jLabel1.setIcon(format); //where I put my image
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;

           case 2:

                  //[...]  //I have 360 cases

    }
} // close state changed
```

Comment: What's the point of a `PreparedStatement` when you write code like `String sql = "select imga from test where deg ='" + x + "'";`?

Comment: PreparedStatement pstm = conn.prepareStatement("select imga from test where deg ='" + x + "'");
ResultSet rs = pstm.executeQuery(); //it's ok now?

Comment: You didn't get my point. The whole purpose of `PreparedStatement`s is so that the database can cache queries. For this reason, you should use parametrized queries. For example `select imga from test where deg = ?`. If you directly append values, not only is it poorly performant, it is also prone to SQL injection attacks. Please go read up on `PreparedStatement`s before you use them.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to save the images in a longblob anyway? Can't you store them within the Jar itself. If you still want to retrieve from Database longblob consider using Caching to load your longblobs from the database and cache it in the local system using a Initializing Asynchronous Thread when your Swing application starts up.

Comment: The problem why I don't store it in Jar itself is that I have a lot of images, not just 360 cases, I have multiple of 360 cases. I'm using longblob because I have a previous problem with blob, and it is that for some reason the image it is not fully loaded (appear with dead pixels, because of limitation of blob). It is interesting your idea with caching, but imagine that I have my MySQL table equal with 1 GB, imagine that you can wait 1 hour to cache all the data.